# iPhone: Run UIImagePickerController and AVAudioSession simultaneously

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, avaudiosession

I have an app that has a UIImagePickerController up permanently, but I also want to access AVAudioSession.

However AVAudioSession receives an interuption notification when the UIImagePickerController is launched.

Is there any way to have both an AVAudioSession and a UIImagePickerController running simultanaeouly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the audio interruption, and when interruption ends you need to continue your audio playback,
Here is the details that how to do 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioInterruptions/HandlingAudioInterruptions.html

Comment: Yes but the problem is that because the UIImagePickerController is continuously running, the interruption never ends. The issue is to run both *simultaneously*.